# A variable exists in locals(), but can't be accessed in the current local scope

Tags: python, scope, exec

Here's a piece of simple code that generates a variable `b` in the scope of `g()` by using `exec()`:

```
def g():
    print("Locals:", locals().keys())
    exec("b=1")
    print("Locals:", locals().keys())
    print(locals()['b'])
    print(b)

g()
```

Output:

```
Locals: dict_keys([])
Locals: dict_keys(['b'])
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    g()
  File "test.py", line 8, in g
    print(b)
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

The variable `b` exists in `locals()`. Why cannot `b` be accessed? I am using Python 3.8.10

Comment: What does `help(locals)` say?

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/exec look at number 4

Comment: @KellyBundy It says "Return a dictionary containing the current scope's local variables".

Comment: @AndrewRyan Thanks. But I am still confused. `b` exists in the current local scope as shown in the output. Why can't it be printed?

Comment: @Frank And then it says, "NOTE: Whether or not updates to this dictionary will affect name lookups in the local scope and vice-versa is *implementation dependent* and not covered by any backwards compatibility guarantees."

Comment: @JohnKugelman  Thanks! What does "Whether or not updates to this dictionary will affect name lookups in the local scope" mean? What's the implication?

Answer (score 1):

[`exec`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) says:

> **Note:** The default *locals* act as described for function `locals()` below: modifications to the default *locals* dictionary should not be attempted. Pass an explicit *locals* dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on *locals* after function `exec()` returns.

[`locals`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) says:

> **Note:** The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

Comment: I didn't notice the second note in `exec`'s documentation at first glance. Thanks!